# JsReport load environment variable into resouce

Tags: docker, jsreport

I am using JsReport from Docker: https://hub.docker.com/r/jsreport/jsreport/

I have a resource file template inside JsReport:

```
{
    "env": {
        "a": "a-value",
        "b": "b-value"
    }
}
```

DockerFile is:

```
FROM jsreport/jsreport:2.6.1
EXPOSE 5488
COPY jsreport.config.json /jsreport/
COPY templates /jsreport/data
```

How can I change value of `a` and `b` when i start the container?

I managed to do it with adding `ENTRYPOINT` in dockerfile.

Comment: Do you mean after you start the container?
Normaly you change the environment variables in dockerfile using "ENV" or in command line using "-e a=a-value"

Comment: @JanBlaha yes, i managed to do that by starting the container using '-e'' and giving the command on docker build to evaluate envs in a file. But maybe there is better option than using `eval` but this container does not have every command, and i do not want to install them.

Comment: And `envsubst` is not installed in this container by default.

Comment: I think passing env in args or in dockerfile is the right way to do it.